# Simple facebook login test app will not launch

Tags: android, facebook

I'm making an app that needs to login with facebook and then start maps. It crashes instantly on my phone with "has unfortunaly stopped working". It seems to be the facebook SDK widget button that I use for login, but I cant figure out how to fix it

```
  09-15 22:06:32.890  10289-10289/com.example.nan.spymap E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.nan.spymap, PID: 10289
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.nan.spymap/com.example.nan.spymap.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
            at com.example.nan.spymap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
                at com.example.nan.spymap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.
            at com.facebook.internal.Validate.sdkInitialized(Validate.java:136)
            at com.facebook.AccessTokenTracker.<init>(AccessTokenTracker.java:55)
            at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton$2.<init>(LoginButton.java:561)
            at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.configureButton(LoginButton.java:561)
            at com.facebook.FacebookButtonBase.<init>(FacebookButtonBase.java:66)
            at com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton.<init>(LoginButton.java:200)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2145)
                at com.example.nan.spymap.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                at    android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at      com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

My manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nan.spymap" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="16dp"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        />

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.nan.spymap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    private TextView info;
    private LoginButton loginButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                info.setText("User ID:  " +
                        loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId() + "\n" +
                        "Auth Token: " + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken());
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                info.setText("Login attempt cancelled.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

My gradle build

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.nan.spymap"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories { mavenCentral() }

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it says what's wrong in the stack trace:

```
 Caused by: The SDK has not been initialized, make sure to call FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize() first.
```

The initialization is done AFTER the layout xml is loaded (in setContentView() ).

Initialize the SDK before or in your Application class.

Comment: But I do;         FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: I got it to work by calling the initialisation as the first thing ! :)